# Rails 4 - How do I structure this model relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, activemodel

In my app, I have two models, `Task` and `Guideline`. Each `Task` can have many `Guidelines`, and each `Guideline` can belong to many `Tasks`. How would I set up the relationship between these two models, if it is even possible with `ActiveRecord`? I have thought about structuring it like so:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guidelines
end

class Guideline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end
```

However, my understanding is that `belongs_to` will associate a `Guideline` to only one `Task` by setting its `task_id` field. This means that, if a given `Guideline` is assigned to another `Task`, the first association will be lost. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have looked into the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, but `Guidelines` cannot have any `Tasks`; they can only belong to many tasks. I currently have a system in which I store in an array the IDs of all the selected `Guidelines` for a given `Task`, but I would prefer to use built-in associations if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Many to many relationship? =)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still fundamentally a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, with a join table:

```
+-------+     +-----------------+     +------------+
| Tasks |-----| GuidelinesTasks |-----| Guidelines |
+-------+     +-----------------+     +------------+
```

In reality, your model is that a guideline has many tasks as well as tasks having many guidelines. The fact that a guideline “belongs to many” is how you interpret it is a purely application-level item that has no relationship to the actual data model.

In Rails, you can model this a couple of ways depending on whether your `guidelines_tasks` table itself has values you wish to track. Both use the same data structure:

```
# Migration
class AddTasksAndGuidelines < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tasks do |t|
      …
    end

    create_table :guidelines do |t|
      …
    end

    create_join_table :guidelines, :tasks
  end
end
```

With this, the first model is the classic `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
# habtm
class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :guidelines
end

class Guidelines < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
end
```

The second model—useful if `GuidelinesTask` has attributes of its own is reflexive `has_many through:`:

```
class Tasks < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guidelines_tasks
  has_many :guidelines, through: :guidelines_tasks
end

class GuidelinesTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :guidelines
end

class Guidelines < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :guidelines_tasks
  has_many :tasks, through: :guidelines_tasks
end
```

Either will work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, especially the interpretation part! I'm thinking about it, and I do have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship without me realizing it. In which models would I specify that association? Both?

Comment: You would put it on both. I have expanded this my answer to provide a couple of different options for this. Either works, but one requires an additional model fronting a table required regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. It allow you make things like: `Task.first.guidlines` (and `Guidline.first.tasks`, if you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can use has_and_belongs_to_many association

Your model code will be

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :guidelines
```

end

class Guideline < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
```

end

Also you need to create a table in database named guidelines_tasks with following migration code
create_table :guidelines_tasks, id: false do |t|

```
  t.belongs_to :guideline, index: true
  t.belongs_to :task, index: true

end
```